# Creating an array on the fly in PHP

Tags: php

I'm stuck. I need to create an array based on a number provided, and I cant think of any way to do it.

What needs to happen is this: 
If the number is `1` the array need to be be `array("2","3","4","10")`

If the number is `2` the array need to be be `array("3","4","10")`

If the number is `3` the array need to be be `array("4","10")`

If the number is `4` the array need to be be `array("10")`

If the number is `10` no array needed.

Other than doing it with a lot of `ifs` and `elseifs`, is there a more elegant way to do this? This is just for this question. The actual thing is even worse.

My approach:

```
if ($num == 1) {
    $array = array("2","3","4","10");
} elseif ($num == 2) {
    $array = array("3","4","10");
} etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution:

```
$source = array(null,"2","3","4","10");
$array = array_slice($source, $number);
```

Test cases:

```
foreach ([1,2,3,4,10] as $n) {
    $array = array_slice($source, $n);
    print_r($array);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 10
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 10
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 10
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10
)
Array
(
)
```

### [**Demo**](https://eval.in/94337)

Comment: What if there's another element after 10? Or if the array was reversed? It won't work then: https://eval.in/94392. As the question says: "The actual thing is even worse.", implying that there are more numbers in the array.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 10);

$result = array_slice($array, array_search($num, $array) + 1);
```

Example:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 10);

foreach ($array as $num)
{
  echo '<pre>' . print_r(array_slice($array, array_search($num, $array) + 1), TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
```

This gives:

```
1:
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 10
)

2:
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 10
)

3:
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 10
)

4:
Array
(
    [0] => 10
)

10:
Array
(
)
```

Comment: An `array_search()` isn't required. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21315204/)

Comment: It is if the array doesn't just contain consecutive numbers starting at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(); // starting array
switch($n) { // your number here
  case 1:
    $arr[] = 2;
    // fallback

  case 2:
    $arr[] = 3;
    // fallback

  case 3:
    $arr[] = 4;
    // fallback

  case 4:
    $arr[] = 10;
    // fallback

  case 10: break; // done
}
```

Now you have your array in `$arr`, based on the entry point it will contain only desided values.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. If I'm following correctly, the output in `$arr` will have only one value...

Comment: No, you are wrong. Please read up on PHP switch, since there are no breaks except for the last case, this produces the desired array.

Comment: @War10ck please review your downvote, and try the code yourself if you wish.

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding. I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = 10;
$source = array("2","3","4","10");
$i = $num;
$array = array();
while ($i <= 4):
    $array[] = $source[$i-1];
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: When `$num = 10` your array index will be out of range (`$i = $num - 1 ` -> `$i = 10 -1 === 9`). `$array[9]` does not exist and is out of range...

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm new to stackoverflow and didn't realize I have to provide perfect cookie cutter code for people to implement.

Comment: @borkith You're supposed to post code that is as good as possible, or better yet, explain how your code works such that the OP comes away with a better understanding of what you did. It's not necessary for your to work when copy and pasted, but it should be free from blatant errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
$origin = array("1","2","3","4","10");
$flag = false;
$array = array();
foreach($origin as $value){
    if($flag == true){
        $array[] = $value;
        continue;
    }
    if($value == $num){
        $flag = true;
    }
}
```